# How come when I try to cd into a new parition nothing happens?

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

My primary partition is C:\

But I want to cd into G:\

When I type in on command prompt "cd G:\", nothing happens. It just prints the directory I'm in which is C:\

My OS is Windows 8.

Comment: You need to use `cd /d` to change the drive you're currently in, as explained in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731237.aspx).

Comment: @OP: Note C: is not a partition. It is volume. There is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just type "G:" because "cd" is only for changing directory within a root node (aka drive).

Comment: Actually, you could also use `cd /d G:`